# Dart null safety - Returning a none nullable type

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-null-safety

I am completely new to the new Dart Null Safety and am trying to convert one of my projects and learn it. I'm getting a little confused with one error I received on a function, where it is returning a type. Here is the code:

```
Exercise getExerciseByID(String exerciseId) {
for (var exercise in _exercises) {
  if (exercise.id == exerciseId) {
    return exercise;
  } 
}
}
```

The error I am receiving is as follows:

> The body might complete normally, causing 'null' to be returned, but the return type, 'Exercise', is a potentially non-nullable type. (Documentation)  Try adding either a return or a throw statement at the end.

I am wondering what should I be doing/ returning in this case? Any advice on this would be really helpful. Thanks so much.

Comment: please can you mention your error!

Comment: What should happen if `exerciseId` is not found?  You have a few choices: A. Return `null` and make `getExerciseByID` return a `Exercise?` instead. B. Construct and return a sentinel `Exercise` object that represents an invalid result. C. `throw` an exception.

Comment: Thanks @Manishyadav , I have added the Error text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because you have implicit `return null` here. If none of `if` statements will be fulfilled, `excersise` will not be returned, therefore ther result will be null.

```
Exercise getExerciseByID(String exerciseId) {
for (var exercise in _exercises) {
  if (exercise.id == exerciseId) {
    return exercise;
  } 
}
 return null; //this is what it complains, that the result might be null while you declare non null response
}
```

Options (alternatives):

1. Change return declaration to nullable type (jamesdlin) `Exercise?`
2. Throw exception at the end instead of returning `null`
3. Always return something - eg default value or 'nothing found value'

Answer (score 1):

add return at the end of the method in case the if condition is not true.

or you can use simple firstWhere method like:

```
return _exercises.firstWhere((exercise) => exercise.id == exerciseId);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting that error because your return statement is inside of if condition, so it assumes that it can possibly never return a value (if all conditions fail). So this could be solution for you:

```
Exercise getExerciseByID(String exerciseId) {
    // initialize some default value to return if all conditions fail
    Exercise returnValue = Exercise();
    for (var exercise in _exercises) {
      if (exercise.id == exerciseId) {
        // if found update your initial value with found one
        returnValue = exercise;
        // stop for loop after finding right value
        break;
      }
    }
    return returnValue;
  }
```